# Applet jar generated with JDK 1.6 compiler on a system with JRE 1.5

Tags: java, applet

Can a applet compiled with JDK 1.6(but not using any new features of 1.6) work on systems having JRE 1.5?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the code was compiled using compiler flag `-target 1.6` (which is default for 1.6 JDK) - then it **will not** run on 1.5 JRE.

However, if the flag `-target 1.5` was used - then it **will** work properly on 1.5 JRE.

Comment: *"then it **will** work properly on 1.5 JRE."*  Change that **will** to a **might** and that statement would be correct.   Use the ***-bootclasspath*** option as well.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hm, are you sure 'will' is not appropriate? If you look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options , you can see this: `-target version
Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM. Class files >>will<< run on the specified target and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM.`

Comment: -target **will not** guarantee that the classes, methods and attributes of the earlier JRE are the only ones used in the client code.  That is where the `-bootclasspath` (and `extdirs`) comes in.  To quote from the paragraph above the one you quoted, *"It is important to use **-bootclasspath** and **-extdirs** when cross-compiling;"* -1 for your blinkered reading of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentions, you need `-target 1.5` to generate 1.5 code. In order to use `-target 1.5` you also need to set `-source 1.5`. Using any part of the 1.6 library that is not used in 1.5 will also cause a fail at run time, so use `-bootclasspath` to point to a 1.5 `rt.jar`. For completeness the "external directories" (libraries available to almost all code) should be set (probably to something empty) with, IIRC, `-Dext.dirs`.

Comment: Lucky you chimed in with the only correct answer of the 3 offered.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiled code will require JRE 1.6 or later. JDK 1.6 will generate Java .class files with version 50.0 while 1.5 uses version 49.0.

Use `javac -target 1.5` to generate .class files that JRE 1.5 can use. See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options

Comment: Use `-bootclasspath`/`-extdirs` as well.  See the accepted answer for more discussion.